# Regex Named Backreference for Length Variable

Tags: regex, regex-group

Can we use a named back reference as a length variable later in a regex?

If I have some data that looks like `<length><variable length digits>`

e.g.

- `0512345`
- `041234`
- `03123`

Can I write a regex similar to `(?P<length>\d{2})(\d{length})` to always capture the `length` from the first two digits and then the next `length` digits?

Comment: No, you will have to do that in two steps: 1) extract the digits, 2) try to capture that many digits up to the end of string starting with the third if any. Judging by the named group syntax, you are using Python `re`, right?

Comment: If you have an upper bound to the length, you could write something like `00|01\d|02\d{2}|03\d{3}|...` and so on - but that seems unlikely to be the best solution.

Comment: sounds like it might need to be @jasonharper's idea if i need purely regex! thanks for verifying for me, i had a strong hint that either of these solutions would be the way forward.